# Retrofit says auth token exists when logged out

Tags: java, android, authentication, retrofit, retrofit2

When I log into my account in my app, I save an auth token in my SharedPreferences, like this:

```
PreferenceUtils.setAuthToken(LoginActivity.this, authToken);
```

Here is my `PreferenceUtils` class:

```
public class PreferenceUtils {
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static String getAuthToken(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sp.getString("auth_token", null);
    }

    public static void setAuthToken(Context context, final String token) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putString("auth_token", token).apply();
    }
}
```

When I log out of the account, I delete the auth token by calling the `logOut()` method in my `UserUtils` class:

```
public class UserUtils {
    public static void logOut(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.remove("auth_token");
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

However, even after logging out of my account and removing the auth token from SharedPreferences, all Retrofit calls **still** somehow have the auth token saved and I'm not sure how.

In other words, when I log out of my account and Retrofit makes a new call, it will print out the auth token that I thought I had deleted when the user logged out.

Only when I *restart* my app does the auth token get fully removed.

Why is it doing this?

Here is my Retrofit client class (note the comment):

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // THIS STILL PRINTS THE AUTH TOKEN EVEN AFTER I'VE
                    // REMOVED IT FROM THE SHARED PREFERENCES
                    Log.d("AUTH TOKEN", authToken);

                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
        }

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: You are removing the auth token from a persistent storage (Shared Preferences) and not from volatile storage (memory). Try to scope the `authToken` variable to class and then nullify it when you remove auth token from Shared Preferences

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason you still are seeing the token is because while you delete the token from the share preferences, you never reset the variable in the program. You need to make sure that you set the variable to null or empty, not just delete it from shared preferences.

Comment: What do you mean set the variable to null? Do you mean call `setAuthToken(context, null)` and THEN remove the SharedPreference?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work. You can definitely try it, but if the variable that is passed into `createService`  is retaining the value of the token, you're going to have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing `setAuthToken(context, null)`, but it's still retaining the value of the token. If that's not what you meant by your answer, what did you mean by "reseting the variable in the program" by setting it null or empty?

Comment: If you look at the method signature for `CreateService` it looks like: ` public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) ` The `authToken` is being passed in, find out where, and make sure that the variable is set to `null`. Chances are that the value is set using `getAuthToken` when the program starts, and the value is retained in memory until the program is killed, at which point it is retrieved again. So you need to make sure that you are setting that value to null too when you set the `SharedPreference` value to `null`.

Comment: So I found where the `authToken` is being passed to `createService()`, and the value is null. But if I add a `Log.d("AUTH TOKEN", authToken)` in the `createService()` method, it will output the auth token that I thought I had deleted. In other words, it's passing null to the method, but the method is somehow still printing the incorrect auth token. Not sure what to do. :/

Comment: @user423156 It's because the interceptor you added is still alive in the `httpClient`. Once you've removed the token (or pass a `null` to the `createService()` method, you need to remove the interceptor as well.

Comment: @peitek That was the solution, thanks! Write a full answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you requested, here is my previous comment as an answer:

It's because the interceptor you added is still alive in the `httpClient`. Once you've removed the token (or pass a `null` to the `createService()` method, you need to remove the interceptor as well.